# How to set width of ListBox with Java in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Since Vaadin Flow the ListBox is implemented for ListSelect. But now I have a problem because I can't setWidth.

```
private final ListBox<Absence> lbRequests=new ListBox<>();
lbRequests.setWidth("100%");//setWidth isn't exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `setWidth()` method is derived from `HasSize` and not from `Component`. `ListBox` does not implement `HasSize`.

To be able to set width and height of a `ListBox`, you can make your own Class which you then use instead of `ListBox`:

```
public class SizedListBox<T> extends ListBox<T> implements HasSize {
    public SizedListBox(){
        super();
    }
}

SizedListBox<Absence> lbRequests = new SizedListBox<>();
lbRequests.setWidth("100%"); // exists and works, I tested it
```

As mentioned by @JensJansson: you can also do the same as what HasSize does if you want to fix this for only one instance of ListBox, and thus do not want a new class to use.
`listbox.getElement().getStyle().set("width", "155px");`

**Edit:**  This issue is now already fixed in the master branch and will no longer exist in the next release.

Comment: I was about to do answer exactly the same thing but you were faster! I created a ticket for this: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-list-box-flow/issues/38

Note that you can also do the same as what HasSize does if you want to fix this for only one instance of ListBox, and thus do not want a new class to use. `listbox.getElement().getStyle().set("width", "155px");`

Comment: @JensJansson I am writing a post in the forum as well (link [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17441459/17441460)), because I suspect there is a reason that HasSize is not implemented. in the [java examples](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-list-box/java-examples) of ListBox they are full width but not by using width style

Comment: The issue got fixed and merged to master quite fast. Master is now capable of setting sizes, and the methods will be available in the next release. https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-list-box-flow/issues/38